# How do I read from a correct data address of LIDAR using Arduino in I2C?

Tags: i2c

I need to read the distance data from a lidar in I2C using an Arduino Nano. Currently, this is the code I've written.

```
unsigned int readDistance()
{
  unsigned int dist = 0 ; // LiDAR actually measured distance value. static so we can return previous dist
  
  // step 1: instruct sensor to read echoes
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x10) ; // transmit to device 0x10
  Wire.write(2) ; // sets distance data address (addr)
  Wire.write(3) ; // sets distance data address (addr)
  Wire.endTransmission() ; // stop transmitting
  
  // step 2: wait for readings to happen
  delay(100) ; // datasheet suggests at least 100ms
  
  // step 3: request reading from sensor
  Wire.requestFrom(0x10, 2) ; // request 2 bytes (DIST_L, DIST_H) from slave device #0x10
  dist = Wire.read() ; dist += Wire.read() << 8; // calculate distance value, bit shift high distance
  return dist ; // return updated dist
}
```

But I have a feeling I'm requesting from the wrong data address', since I'm not getting the results I expect (ie. varying distance data). Furthermore, I used an I2C scanner which 100% confirms the lidar is on the (default address) of 0x10.

Datasheet of (TF02 Pro): https://www.unmannedtechshop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/TF02-Pro-Product-Manual-Alpha.pdf

**Question: am i reading from the right data address**
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which information on which page are you following?

Comment: i'm quite new to arduino so please bear with me. are you talking about the datasheet for the lidar which I'm getting the address' from? that's @ https://www.unmannedtechshop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/TF02-Pro-Product-Manual-Alpha.pdf

Comment: It looks to me like you have to send the same things through i2c as you would through UART. It's not your typical i2c device.

Comment: What results are you getting exactly? If your code is not stalling or failing then I doubt it’s an address issue. 
Do you maybe have access to an oscilloscope or I2C test device  to see what’s happening on the I2C bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, some i2c devices are configured such that data is only present in said registers after continually issuing 'read commands'.

In this case, the read command was: 5A 05 00 01 60

Amended code:

```
unsigned int readDistance()
{
  unsigned int dist = 0 ; // LiDAR actually measured distance value
  
  // step 1: instruct sensor to read echoes
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x10) ; // transmit to device 0x10
  Wire.write(0x5A) ; // some read command.
  Wire.write(0x05) ;
  Wire.write(0x00) ;
  Wire.write(0x01) ;
  Wire.write(0x60) ;
  Wire.endTransmission() ; // stop transmitting
  
  // step 2: wait for readings to happen
  delay(100) ; // datasheet suggests at least 100ms
  
  // step 3: request reading from sensor
  Wire.requestFrom(0x10, 4) ; // request first 4 bytes from slave device #0x10
  Wire.read() ; Wire.read() ; //ignore header bytes
  // remaining two bytes for distance (DIST_L, DIST_H) 
  dist = Wire.read() ; dist += Wire.read() << 8 ; // calculate distance value, bit shift high distance
  return dist ; // return updated dist
}
```